# Database state is showing as 'Restoring' for a longtime when I do with NORECOVERY option

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-backups, database-restore

I have a two backup files (MS SQL SERVER)
1) Demo.bak
2)DemoDiff.bak

I want to restore the Base database (Demo.bak) then Differential backup (DemoDiff.bak).
As I need to restore the differential database then I have to restore my base database with NORECOVERY option. But, when I restore with NORECOVERY option the database state is showing as 'Restoring' for a long time (Actually it as only 3519 KB size).

Can anyone help me out from this?

Comment: Are you doing this through the wizard or TSQL?

Comment: Both ways I tried. It is behaving same

Comment: That's normal. Now you need to restore the differential and that will bring it to an ONLINE state. You should read the doco

Answer (score 1):

RESTORING is the expected state of a database after a RESTORE with NORECOVERY.  You can then apply transaction log backups or a differential backup.

Recovery takes the database from RESTORING to ONLINE.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 
Here is my question
I need to run differential backup script after full backup script for restore. So,    I need to use NORECOVERY option for my full backup restore script. If I use NORECOVERY option then the Database state is showing as *Restoring* (and not changing to other state). Database size is only 3159 KB only.

Comment: So what is your question again?

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I get out of my problem?
From last two day database (very small DB) status is showing as 'Restoring'  status. I cannot restore my differential backup unless I successfully restore my base backup.

Comment: The database is needs to be in RESTORING mode after restoring the full backup and before restoring the differential.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-differential-database-backup-sql-server#TsqlProcedure

Answer (score 0):

You can restore log files till the database is no recovery mode. If the database is recovered it will be in operation and it can continue database operation. If the database has another operations we cannot restore further log as the chain of the log file after the database is recovered is meaningless. This is the reason why the database has to be norecovery state when it is restored.

There are three different ways to recover the database.

1) Recover the database manually with following command.

RESTORE DATABASE database_name WITH RECOVERY

2) Recover the database with the last log file.

RESTORE LOG database_name FROM backup_device WITH RECOVERY

3) Recover the database when bak is restored

RESTORE DATABASE database_name FROM backup_device WITH RECOVERY

Comment: I need to restore the Differential backup after Full backup. So, I should use NORECOVERY only. Correct me if I am wrong.